# How to print multi-line string into a blob?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, blob

I have a dictionary which I want to print to a txt file in multiple lines.

To achieve this, I am:
1) Converting the dict to string via JSON.stringify(dict)
2) Inputting the string to a Blob and saving it

The trouble I'm having is that the output is a really ugly 1-line result of the dictionary, like this:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3",etc}
```

But I want it like this:

```
key1:value1  
key2:value2
key3:value3  
etc.
```

How can I achieve this?

```
result = JSON.stringify(dict);

// Create blob instance and input the string
var blob1 = new Blob([result], { type: "text/plain" });
url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob1);

// Create link to download the blob as txt file
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = url;
a.setAttribute("download","My Open Tabs");
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Comment: Use the third argument of JSON.stringify => `JSON.stringify(dict, null, '  ');`. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a similar effect to what you expect, you can add arguments to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
JSON.stringify({ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, null, '\n'); // Unix
JSON.stringify({ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }, null, '\r\n'); // Windows
```

Thank you, @Fefux for mentioning about the difference between Windows and Unix!

The third argument accepts the desired delimiter.

Comment: Hmm it works when I console.log it but the txt file from the blob still flattens it...

Comment: Still flattens it. I think createObjectURL(blob1) is flattening it. Wonder if there is another way around this :/

Comment: `\n` is Unix new line style. If you work with windows, replace `\n` by `\r\n`. It can works